# Incorrect iteration of loop in Assembler

Tags: c, arrays, loops, assembly, nasm

Using nasm with 32bit assembler code yields an unexpected result for my current attempts to write a loop which basically swaps elements of a vector. Given that `ESI` and `EDI` point to two different vectors (storing `double` values) and `ECX` the number `n` describing to swap the first `n` elements from `[ESI]` with the first `n` elements from `[EDI]` my attempts so far look like this:

```
; c-call: dswap(int n, double* dx, int unused1, double* dy, int unused2)
_dswap:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    pusha
    mov esi, [ebp+12] ; dx
    mov edi, [ebp+20] ; dy
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]  ; n
    ; unused1 and unused2 obviously unused for the moment
mainLoop:
    cmp ecx, 0
    je exitFunction
    mov eax, [esi + 4 * ecx]
    mov ebx, [edi + 4 * ecx]
    mov [esi + 4 * ecx], ebx
    mov [edi + 4 * ecx], eax
    dec ecx
    jmp mainLoop
exitFunction:
    popa
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I am getting some unexpected behavior. Calling `dswap` on `(1,2,3)` with `(4,5,6)` and `n=3` only swaps the first two elements in both vectors thus making me think what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with doubles, but you are only multiplying `ecx` by 4 (the size of a float). Since the size of a double is 8, you should multiply by 8.

Another problem is that you do not decrement `ecx` before you multiply by it. Assuming `n` is passed as 3, you will be swapping dx[3] with dy[3] on the first iteration, but that is beyond the ends of the arrays. To fix this, you can decrement `ecx` before you do the swaps.

Comment: After applying your proposed changes my vectors aren't modified at all. They remain unchanged now.

Comment: Since a double is 8 bytes you need 4 32-bit swaps now. 2 is not sufficient.

Comment: Okay that will take my some time to figure out how to implement this.

Comment: Any particular reason you are writing it in Assembly? If it is because of speed, then it is likely that your version is less efficient than what a compiler would generate.

Comment: Our assignment specifically states that this function should be implemented in Assembler. And thanks for the hint with the additional swaps - it works now as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Double precision values are usually stored in 8-bytes cells. In your loop youe are assuming a 4-bytes cell, that's why only half of array is swapped.